# Implementing Unique Contraint with ValidateEntity gives "The given key was not present in the dictionary" error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, unique, dbcontext

While in search of trying to implement unique key validations for my db using EF CodeFirst/Mvc3 I came upon this post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/05/27/ef-4-1-validation.aspx which gave an example on how to do it by using `IValidateObject` for my object model:

```
public class Category : IValidatableObject
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var testContext = (TestContext)validationContext.Items["Context"];

        if (testContext.Categories.Any(
            c => c.CategoryName == CategoryName && c.CategoryID != CategoryID))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("A category with the same name already exists!", new[] { "CategoryName" });
        }

        yield break;
    }
}
```

and overriding `DbEntityValidationResult ValidateEntity`:

```
public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Test.Models.Category> Categories { get; set; }

    protected override DbEntityValidationResult ValidateEntity( DbEntityEntry entityEntry, IDictionary<object, object> items)
    {
        var myItems = new Dictionary<object, object>();
        myItems.Add("Context", this);
        return base.ValidateEntity(entityEntry, myItems);
    }

}
```

And the action on the controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Category category)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        categoryRepository.InsertOrUpdate(category);
        categoryRepository.Save();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    } else {
        return View();
    }
}
```

But I get the error: `"The given key was not present in the dictionary."` for the line

```
var testContext = (TestContext)validationContext.Items["Context"];
```

It seems like Validate on the object is getting called which accesses "Context" before its set in the override ValidateEntity code.

At first I thought it could have been ModelState.Isvalid triggering validate too early but it wasn't.

Anyone know what I'm missing here or what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Model.IsValid` definitely triggers it too early and perhaps something else. `IValidatableObject` is global interface used by both MVC and EF but your method in `DbContext` is called only when you call `SaveChanges` on the context so any usage of `IValidatableObject` prior to calling `SaveChanges` will result in the exception. You must use another approach if you want to validate your entity this way. For example store context in `HttpContext.Items` - you can create custom action filter and instantiate and store the context before the operation call and dispose it after operation call - hopefully it will cover all problems.

Comment: Is there a "Best practice" approach to validating uniqueness that you could suggest? I didn't really find much information regarding this besides the fact that EF doesn't really have a built in way to handle it yet which lead me to that ado.net team blog with the broken code. What you suggested would seem to do the trick making unit testing easier though. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think there is any best practice for validating uniqueness because the only reliable way is unique index in database and catching exception after saving changes. The reason is that there can be created another entity with the same value between your validation in application and your call to save changes.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem... Then after a lot of Googling I finally found this:

[Exercise 3: Using IValidatableObject Custom Validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvccustomvalidation_topic4.aspx)

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    MusicStoreEntities storeDB = new MusicStoreEntities();

    if (storeDB.Albums.Any(
                       a => a.Title.Trim().ToUpper() == this.Title.Trim().ToUpper() &&
                       a.ArtistId == (int)this.ArtistId))
    {
        yield return new ValidationResult("Existing Album", new string[] { "Title" });
    }
}
```

As you see in their example, they instantiate a new `Context` and as such there's no need for `validationContext.Items["Context"];`. Doing so we won't get this error anymore.